# Bulk Create Websites in IIS 6.0 Management Console

Tags: iis-6

I have a list of about 80 websites that I want to create on a fresh IIS install. There is going to be only one IP and all websites be host-header'd. Is there any tool that will let me do this in one go as I am sure doing it one by one must be the worst option.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: should I ask this question there?